# Dúvida Consumir Web Service em Wordpress

Tags: jquery, json, wordpress, web-service

Tenho um site em wordpress, feito por mim mesmo, se chama Circuito Escolar, nele eu preciso consumir os dados de um webservice para gerenciamento de campeonatos, equipes, jogos, alunos, etc...
A empresa responsável pelo Web Service me passou pdf's com um exemplo de como puxar esses dados, mas como nunca fiz isso, infelizmente não estou conseguindo chamar as informações, por favor, se puderem me passar apenas um exemplo de como se faz isso, ficaria muito grato! Att

aqui está uma de minhas tentativas, está tudo errado

```
$api_request = 'https://www.sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SDE78623GVS7234GNMSKLano=&status=';
    $response = wp_remote_get( $api_request ).html();
    $(function() {
    $("texte").html();
    });
```

edit: mais uma tentativa falha, eu só preciso entender como funciona a estrutura...

```js
 $url = 'https://www.sportsmanager.com.br/api/campeonatos?email=circuitoescolar@circuitoescolar.com.br&token=SLSO8342HSDE7GVS7234GNL&ano2018&status=A';
 $response = wp_remote_get( $url );
 $api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );
 print_r ($api_response);
 echo $api_response;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cuide para não deixar seu e-mail e token no código ou nas imagens da pergunta. Pois outras pessoas podem usar essa informação

Comment: Obrigado pela dica! eu dei uma embaralhada nos números